# UIButton Cuts off Image

Tags: ios, xcode, button, interface-builder, uibutton

I am trying to create custom buttons, and I created one in photoshop and set it to the Background of a UIButton (using Interface Builder). When I run the app however, the image border is removed, but shows back up when highlighted. I want the border to show up always. How do I change this?

Comment: make sure the dimensions are correct between image and button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a advise u should create 3 images for the button ., one image for background,and other two images stage config based on their state ..